# Finite groups with few double cosets with respect to abelian subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

The following question is motivated by the study of certain tensor categories, namely integral near-group categories.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\subset G$ be a subgroup. Is it possible to give a complete classification (or at least give some examples) satisfying the following conditions:

1) $H$ is abelian;

2) $G$ is the union of the normalizer $N$ of $H$ and exactly one more double coset with respect to $H$.

Pairs $(G,H)$ satisfying the additional condition below is of special interest:

3) the double coset not contained in $N$ consists of $|H|^2$ elements (which is maximal
possible size)

Known examples satisfying 1), 2) and 3):

a) $G=F_q\rtimes F_q^*$ and $H=F_q^*$ (here $F_q$ is a finite field)

b) $G=S_4$ and $H$ is a non-normal subgroup of order 4.

An easy observation is that condition 2) implies that $G-$action on $G/N$ is 2-transitive but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: If $S \subset H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, Then $(G,H)$ satisfies the condition if and only if $(G/S,H/S)$ does. Condition 3 is equivalent to the condition that there is no nontrivial $S$, as if $HgH$ is the unique coset of size greater than $|H|$, but has size less than $|H|^2$, then $H \cap gH g^{-1}$ is such a subgroup. So we might as well assume this condition, in which case $G$ is a transitive permutation group acting on $G/H$ where the stabilizer of a point abelian. Then $|G/H| =|N/H|+|H|$, but $|N/H|$ divides $|G/H|$, so $|N/H|$ divides $|H|$.

Comment: If $|N/H|=1$ then $G$ is a Frobenius group. From this you can deduce that $H$ is cyclic and acts on a nilpotent group $K$ by conjugation, which fixes the identity and acts transitively on the rest. Thus $K$ can only be a $\mathbb F_p$-vector space, and since $H$ acts simply transitively it gives the nonzero vectors a group structure, making $K$ into a finite field. So example a) is the only example when $|N/H|$ is $1$ and condition $3$ is true.

Answer (score 10):

We can construct such a group in the following way:

First take $\mathbb F_q \rtimes \mathbb F_q^{\times}$.

Then take a product of two isomorphic abelian groups $X \times Y$, where $X\cong Y$. (This notation appears strange but is more convenient.)

Choose an action of $\mathbb F_q \rtimes \mathbb F_q^{\times}$ on $X\times Y$ by automorphisms where $\mathbb F_q^{\times}$ fixes $X$ but some element sends $X$ to $Y$.

Then choose an extension $1 \to X \times Y \to G \to \mathbb F_q \rtimes \mathbb F_q^{\times}$ where previous action is the action by conjugation and the inverse image of $\mathbb F_q^{\times}$ has a normal subgroup $H$ containing $X$ with complement $Y$.
$G,H$ is a pair of the type you desire. These are the only type of pair satisfying conditions 1 to 3.

The choice of extension is the only fiddly bit in terms of such a classification. I don't know how to classify these types of extensions - maybe by some type of group cohomology? However, extensions of $1 \to X \times Y \to N \to \mathbb F_q^{\times}$ can be easily classified - they consist of pairs of an extension $1 \to X \to H \to \mathbb F_q^\times$ (itself classified by maps $\mathbb F_q^{\times} \to X$) and an action of $Y$ on $H$ which fixes the components, which is just a map $Y \otimes \mathbb F_q^\times \to X$. But I don't know how many lifts each of these will have to the whole group.

But note that lots of easy extensions, like semidirect products, do satisfy these conditions!

---

To prove that this is actually a pair of the type you desire, first note that $H$ is an extension of a cyclic group by an abelian group where the abelian group is central, hence it is abelian.  Then note that the order of $G$ is $q(q-1)|X|^2=|H|^2 +(q-1)|X|^2$, but the normalizer of $H$ contains the inverse image of $\mathbb F_q^{\times}$ so it has size at least $(q-1)|X|^2$, so we just need to find a double coset of size $|H|^2$. Let $g\in g$ be such that $gXg^{-1}=Y$. Then I claim $gHg^{-1} \cap H=1$, producing the coset. Since $g$ cannot be in the inverse image of $\mathbb F_q^{\times}$, the image of $H \cap gHg^{-1}$ in $\mathbb F_q \rtimes \mathbb F_q^{\times}$ is trivial, so any intersection must lie in $X \times Y$. But $H \cap X \times Y = X$, and $gXg^{-1}=Y$, and $X \cap Y=1$, so the intersection is trivial.

---

To prove that every pair satisfying conditions 1,2, and 3 can be described in this way, take the coset $HgH$ of size $|H|^2$. Since it can also be described as the complement of $N$, it is closed under the action of $N$, so $NgH$ has order $|H|^2$ as well. Let $X$ be the subgroup of $H$ which acts trivially on $Ng$ on the right, and let $Y$ be the subgroup of $N$ that acts trivially on $gH$ on the left. Then $X$ is conjugate to $Y$ by $g$,  $|X|=|Y|=|N|/|H|$, and $Y \cap H=1$.

Since $Y\subset N$ and $X \subset H$, $Y$ normalizes $X$. Since $Y\cap X=1$, $XY$ is a subgroup of order $|N/H|^2$. Next we will check that $XY$ acts trivially on $G/N$. $X \subset H$, and $H$ acts on $G/N$ with a single nontrivial orbit, and is abelian, so any subgroup of it that fixes one point fixes every point, so $X$ acts trivially on $G/N$. $Y$ is conjugate to $X$, so $XY$ acts trivially on $G/N$.

Next we see that $XY$ is everything that acts trivially on $G/N$. Indeed, every element that acts trivially must be in $N$, but $|NgN|=|H|^2$, so only $|N|^2/|H|^2=|XY|$ elements can act trivially.

Now we check that $G/(XY)$ is a group of this type. Indeed, the image of $H$ in $G/(XY)$ is abelian, and the action of $H$ on $G/(XY)H= G/N$ is a single nontrivial orbit plus a single trivial orbit, so $G/XY$ is a group of this type and, moreover, a Frobenius group, so as I showed in my comment, it is $\mathbb F_q \rtimes \mathbb F_q^{\times}$.

Now we are done. $XY$, the product of two isomorphic abelian groups, is a normal subgroup with quotient $\mathbb F_q \rtimes \mathbb F_q^{\times}$, which acts by conjugation, with one element sending $X$ to $Y$, but $\mathbb F_q^{\times}$ fixing $X$, since they are both part of the abelian subgroup $H$. $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N$, containing $X$, and $Y$ is a complement, since $Y \cap H=1
$ and $|Y|=|N|/|H|$.

Comment: Dear Will, thanks very much! This is very useful.

Comment: @VictorOstrik: Hopefully this stronger result will be a bit more useful!